# How do I select all from a nested array of JSON objects?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with each row containing JSON objects that look something like this:

```
{
   "Metadata":{
      ...
   },
   "NestedArray":[
      {
         ...,
         ...,
         "Coordinates":[
            {
               "id":"1000",
               "X":"...",
               "Y":"..."
            },
            {
               "id":"1001",
               "X":"...",
               "Y":"..."
            },
            {
               "id":"1003",
               "X":"...",
               "Y":"..."
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

So each object contains a `NestedArray`, which contains another nested array called  `Coordinates`.

```
MyObject.NestedArray[].Coordinates[]
```

What I'm trying to do is query a JSON column in my PostgreSQL table that contains objects such as the one above, and get a resultset of all `Coordinates` objects.

So this is essentially what I want to end up with:

| id | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | . | . |
| 1002 | . | . |
| 1003 | . | . |
| 1004 | . | . |
| 1005 | . | . |
| 1006 | . | . |

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that jsonb_array_elements() will work in this case because there are two nested levels of json arrays. This should be tested intead :

```
SELECT r.item ->> 'id' as id
     , r.item ->> 'X' as X
     , r.item ->> 'Y' as Y
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(your_json_column :: jsonb, '$.NestedArray[*].Coordinates[*]') AS r(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the array, then you can access each key using the `->>` operator:

```
select e.item ->> 'id' as id, 
       e.item ->> 'x' as x,
       e.item ->> 'y' as y
from the_table
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(the_column -> 'NestedArray') as c(o)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(c.o -> 'Coordinates') as e(item)
```

This assumes that `the_column` is defined with the data type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not use `json_array_elements()` instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae37f9edfed512cb19f1424641d6fa2b)

Comment: What do you mean by unnesting the array? I don't have control over the structure of the JSON document.

Comment: `jsonb_array_elements` will unnest the array